# TypeError: undefined is not a function in Karma / Jasmine test on init function in Angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have simple factory in AngularJS:

```
function usersListDataProviderFactory(UserResource, $q) {
    var usersListDataProvider = {},
        queryParams = {};

    init(queryParams);

    return {
        initDataProvider: function (queryParams) {
            init(queryParams);
        },
        getDataProviderPromise: function () {
            return usersListDataProvider;
        }
    };

    function init(queryParams) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        UserResource.getUsers(queryParams).then(function (response) {
            defer.resolve(response);
        }, function (error) {
            defer.reject(error);
        });

        usersListDataProvider = defer.promise;
    }
}
```

I have written tests in Karma / Jasmine that pass after commenting the lines:

```
init(queryParams);
```

When I restore an automatic function call I get a message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'UserResource.getUsers(queryParams).then')
```

I know the problem is the configuration of the test and the moment the spy was created, but I have no idea how to solve the problem. Current test configuration:

```
describe('Service: UsersListDataProvider', function () {
    var usersListDataProvider,
        userResourceStub,
        deferred,
        $rootScope,
        $q;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('UsersList');
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        userResourceStub = {
            getUsers: function (queryParams) {
                return queryParams;
            }
        };

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('UserResource', userResourceStub);
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (_UsersListDataProvider_, _$rootScope_, _$q_) {
        usersListDataProvider = _UsersListDataProvider_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $q = _$q_;

        deferred = _$q_.defer();
    }));

    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn(userResourceStub, 'getUsers').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
    });

    describe('Method: initDataProvider', function () {
        it('');
    });
});
```

Any idea ?